# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: java, android, gradle, compiler-errors

I just updated my Android Studio to version 3.5. When I run App error occurs.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
>
> Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$1 found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0)

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alquickstop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

gradle (app) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add this `configurations {
                all*.exclude group:'android.support.v4.app' module: ‘classes.jar’
                
        }`

Comment: unexpected ':'  and unexpected ' ' in classes.jar error @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0) Duplicate class

You should add

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: where do i need to  add this  configurations

Answer (score 0):

Go to `gradle.properties` and write these two lines of code:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then **clean** and **rebuild** project then run.